# Counting overlapping vehicles at a location in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an issue that i cant seem to figure out. I have a location with 4 parking spots. I also have a list with information when a vehicle come to the parking spot, and when it leaves. How do i count how many vehicles are at the location at the same time?

**Example of data I have**

```
VEHICLE ACTIVITY PLACE STARTTIME ENDTIME
701     PARKING  A     10:16     10:41
711     PARKING  A     09:46     10:11
746     PARKING  A     09:52     10:18
```

[Part of data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zttO.png)

Answer (score 1):

For example:

[image]

Formula in `H2`:

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C4,"A",D2:D4,"<="&TIME(10,40,0),E2:E4,">="&TIME(10,40,0))
```

I'm not a 100% sure about your query but I do believe that `COUNTIFS` is what you are after.

Comment: Thanks! But I think i was a bit unclear. I would also like to know at any time of day how many vehicles are at that location. For example at 11:01 there are 3. And at 11:04 there are 1

Comment: The pattern for you to use is out there so you just need to tweak it for your specific needs @JohBe03